# Conditional SSE/AVX add or zero elements based on compare

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, avx

I have the following `__m128` vectors:

`v_weight`

`v_entropy`

I need to add `v_entropy` to `v_weight` only where elements in `v_weight` are not 0f.

Obviously `_mm_add_ps()` adds all elements regardless.

I can compile up to AVX, but not AVX2.

*EDIT*

I do know beforehand how many elements in `v_weight` will be 0 (there will always be either 0 or the last 1, 2, or 3 elements). If it's easier, how do I zero-out the corresponding elements in `v_entropy`?

Comment: SSE/AVX comparisons return a mask, that you can *and* with your vector.

Comment: Do you know which compare intrinsic has a mask? `_mm_cmp_ps()` is the only applicable compare I see, but it doesn't return a mask.

Comment: I figured it out. `_mm_cmpneq_ps` and `_mm_and_ps`

Comment: Will it ever change which `v_weight` are supposed to be zero? If not, create the `mask` only once and `v_weight &= mask` only before actually using `v_weight`.

Comment: Yes, it will change.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cmpeq/cmpgt instructions create a mask, all ones or all zeros. The overall process goes as follows:

```
auto mask=_mm_cmpeq_ps(_mm_setzero_ps(), w);
mask=_mm_andnot_ps(mask, entropy);
w = _mm_add_ps(w, mask);
```

Other option is to accumulate anyway, but use blendv to select between added/not added.

```
auto w2=_mm_add_ps(e,w);
auto mask=_mm_cmpeq_ps(zero,w);
w=_mm_blendv_ps(w2,w, mask);
```

Third option uses the fact that w+e = 0, when w=0

```
 m=(w==0); // make mask as in above
 w+=e; // add
 w&=~m; // revert adding for w==0
```

(I'm using cmpeq instead of cmpneq to make it usable for integers as well.)

Comment: You can use `_mm_andnot_ps` to avoid casts (and potentially extra latency from bypass delays on some CPUs).  There's also a `blendv_ps` which would be a better choice for FP data; blends have bypass delay between FP and integer even on Sandybridge-family.